# Given a matrix, its spectral norm smaller than one, can we say that the matrix have column of L2 norm smaller than one?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, normed-spaces

Given a matrix $X$, its spectral norm smaller than and equal to one, $\|X\|_2\leq 1$.
can we say that the matrix have column of $\ell_2$ norm smaller than and equal to one? i.e.,
$\|X_i\|_2\leq 1$? where $X_i$ denote the $i$-th column of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\forall i, \ \ \ 1\geq\|X\|_2 = \max_{\|v\|_2=1}\|Xv\|\geq\|Xe_i\|_2 = \|X_i\|_2.
$$